# AFNetworking: setRedirectResponseBlock inside my class NSURLResponse always return null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking classes to interact with  web-service.I am having some problem in that.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest];// using AFHTTPRequestOperation to request Data
[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
        NSLog(@"connection :%@",connection);

        NSLog(@"request :%@",request);

        NSLog(@"response :%@",redirectResponse); question 1:? i get NSURLResponse value is null. output:response :(null)

        return request;

    }];
```

With the help of Breakpoint i check inside the AFNetworking classes (class name : AFURLConnectionOperation.m) whether it getting response from server? Yes its getting response.

```
- (void)setRedirectResponseBlock:(NSURLRequest * (^)(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse))block {

    self.redirectResponse = block;

    NSLog(@"connection :%@",_connection);

    NSLog(@"request :%@",_request);

    NSLog(@"response :%@",_redirectResponse);//getting NSURLResponse from server.(its showing response)  output: response :<__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x46238>

    NSLog(@"block :%@",block);

}
```

My Problem is that when i call [operation setRedirectResponseBlock.....] inside my class NSURLResponse *redirectResponse always have null value but when i check in - (void)setRedirectResponseBlock..... inside the AFURLConnectionOperation.m class NSURLResponse *redirectResponse have some value. Can you Please Help to know that where i am wrong. last one week all days i was googling i couldn't find any answer that related to this.

i am using "theRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;" because i don't want to load all the time from server only if there any modification in header then only i want to call again. for this i need to use "setRedirectResponseBlock" to write below code.

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self]]) {

NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];

NSString *modified = [headers objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];


if (modified) { .......
```

Please Help me to solve this, examples much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for the corresponding delegate method, `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`:

> The delegate can receive this message as a result of modifying a request before it is sent, for example to transform the request’s URL to its canonical form. To detect this case, examine redirectResponse; if it is nil, the message was not sent due to a redirect.

Comment: Yes,i understand.i am using AFHTTPRequestOperation to start operation in my nsoperation class,so my question is there any way to call all that delegate method (didreciverespose,didfinishloading,didfailwitherror,didReceiveData) into my nsopperation class rather than using blocks.I just want to get called those delegate methods in my nsoperation class. can you help me with this?

Comment: The blocks effectively replace all of the delegate methods you would otherwise implement. If you _really_ wanted to, you _could_ re-implement them in a subclass, but this is not something I would recommend.

Comment: connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:
{
    if (self.redirectResponse) {
        NSLog(@"connection :%@",connection);
        NSLog(@"request :%@",request);
        NSLog(@"response :%@",redirectResponse);// is <nil>.
        return self.redirectResponse(connection, request, redirectResponse); i check this redirectResponse is null , still i cannot find where i am wrong.