# AFNetworking sends Get instead of POST

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

```
-(void)uploadUserImageWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIImage *imageTanya = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *m = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyy/filesService.svc/"]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageTanya, 0.5);
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [m POST:@"UploadFile" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"1" fileName:@"1.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@ **** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject, operation.request.URL.absoluteString);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
}
```

while sending request POST it changed into GET because AFNetworking send wrong path when server redirect it method has changed into get 
the wrong path  : "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/UploadFile HTTP/1.1"
when i have created a new project it works fine but in my project it gives me this error
-Xcode Version 5.1 
- AFNetworking 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
m POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mohamedaspnet.com/Nazzelha/filesService.svc/%@", @"UploadFile"] ....
```

Sorry somehow I don't get what the problem is, and if you are looking for to POST to an URL, but the server will redirect it to another URL, for example, http://domain.com/abc ==> 301 ==> http://domain.com/def, then what you are expecting is to POST to http://domain.com/def actually, you should look at this thread [AFNetworking: setRedirectResponseBlock inside my class NSURLResponse always return null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854142/afnetworking-setredirectresponseblock-inside-my-class-nsurlresponse-always-retu)

> According to the documentation for the corresponding delegate method,
>   connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse::
>
> The delegate can receive this message as a result of modifying a
>   request before it is sent, for example to transform the request’s URL
>   to its canonical form. To detect this case, examine redirectResponse;
>   if it is nil, the message was not sent due to a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your request is handled by the Foundation URL Loading System, and is not an AFNetworking issue.
2. You should delete this line, since the `POST:…` method you're calling already enqueues the operation:

   ```
    [op start];
   ```
3. Check the type of redirect your server is sending.  If it's sending HTTP 303, [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) mandates that the request type should be changed to `GET`. It should be sending HTTP 307. See [3xx Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_307#3xx_Redirection) and make sure you're using the correct status code.